# Upload an XML file and update database

Tags: xml, database

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I am not sure that will solve my problem.
This is a simple binary question. Is it possible to have some sort of algorithm that receives XML file and on the click of a button insert all the data in the XML to tables in a database?
Sorry if it's a beginner question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can actually use DataTables to accomplish this.  The DataTable class features a read xml method which will read an xml file and store it into a datatable, which you can then use to update a database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx